# jQuery click() on a nested div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, onclick

The code can probably explain this better than I can:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner1"></div>
    <div class="inner2"></div>
</div>

<script>
$('div').click(function(){
    var class_name = $(this).attr('class');
    do_something(class_name);
});
</script>
```

When I click on the `inner1` div, it runs the `do_something()` with both the `inner1` div AND the `wrapper`.

With the site being built, nested divs are going to happen a lot. Is there a dynamic way to fix this issue and only run the top level div (in this case `inner1`)?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022619/make-content-div-clickable-with-nested-divs

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

```
$('div').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var class_name = $(this).attr('class');
    do_something(class_name);
});
```

---

On the other hand: are you sure this is what you're trying to do? You might want to modify your selector (`$('div')`) to only target the DIV's you want.

Comment: Should be propagation with an a; I can't edit the answer itself to fix it, though.

Comment: Be ware that $(document).on("click", ...) and $("div").on("click") should not be mixed. Otherwise, event propagation does not work as intended.

Answer (score 2):

You need to prevent the event bubbling. With jQuery, you would do this:

```
$('div').click(function(e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();

    // Other Stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're selector is 'div' so on every single div that is clicked this will run. This includes wrapper, inner1, and inner2 in this example.

If you only want inner1 to fire off that function you're code will look like this:

```
$('.inner1').click(function(){
    var class_name = $(this).attr('class');
    do_something(class_name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner1"></div>
    <div class="inner2"></div>
</div>

<script>
$('div').click(function(ev){
    var class_name = $(this).attr('class');
    do_something(class_name);
    ev.stopPropagation();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The event bubbles until you stop it with the `stopPropagation` method:

```
$('div').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  var class_name = $(this).attr('class');
  do_something(class_name);
});
```