# adding click events separate for enclosing divs

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add actions of div click event and I have one div enclosed inside another. and I want click event to be different for each div. but if a div is  enclosed inside another, the click event on inner div does both actions, for example.. Ive added a fiddle and a sample code. How can I make it individual actions alone for each div??

http://jsfiddle.net/Dk8vA/

```
$('#outerDiv').on("click",function(){
     alert("s");    
 });

$('#innerDiv').on("click",function(){
  alert("n");
});
 <div id='outerDiv'><div id='innerDiv'></div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)   to prevent bubbling up of events

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SFpNk/)

```
$('#outerDiv').on("click",function(){
  alert("s");  
});

$('#innerDiv').on("click",function(e){
  alert("n");
  e.stopPropagation();    
});
```

Comment: Is there any difference in adding e.stopPropogation() after the alert and before the alert in this case???

Comment: @user1371896 No it doesn't matter.. All you need to do is to put it in the child event handler to prevent the event from being bubbled up.

Answer (score 2):

Use `e.stopPropagation()` to prevent the event bubble up to the parent.

[Reference Here](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

This prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event. By adding stopPropagation() event doesn't bubble up to its parent `#outerDiv` or further up.

```
$('#innerDiv').on("click",function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
alert("n");

});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NSB5E/)

Answer (score 1):

Using `e.StopPropagation()` will be the your solution.

You can refer to

[jQuery click() on a nested div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324186/jquery-click-on-a-nested-div)